# NI Guitar Rig 6 Buzzes, crackles and hums

Tags: recording, homerecording

I am using a Fender P bass into Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 3rd Gen, Ableton Live 11 running on a new Dell G-5 Windows 10.
I can record and play without using the Guitar Rig 6 plugin without noise, but when I add the plugin to the channel strip  I get noise and the playback volume is incredibly low compared to the input signal. Been searching NI, Ableton, and Focusrite sites as well as Youtube and Google. Nothing.
I also have the stand-alone version of Guitar Rig 6 on my computer with the same problem for most of the presets. The ultra-clean pre-sets play without snap, crackle, and buzz!  Thanks in advance for any advice you may have.

Comment: Have you visited and run over the optimizations suggested by NI for recording on a windows machine, I would also check out Scarlett's optimization tips for windows machines as well. https://support.native-instruments.com/hc/en-us/articles/209571729-Windows-Tuning-Tips-for-Audio-Processing

Comment: The Scarlett's optimization document is amazing. I've worked my way through that and the NI document seems to have much of the same info. I will look at it in more detail.  Thanks!